# Remove NA strings from table (characters) in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

How can I remove NA strings in a simple data frame like the one below, which consists of a single column, in R?

```
head(test)
Column1 
[1] "Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 NA NA NA NA" 
[2] "Gene41 NAGene218 GeneX NA"
[3] "Gene19 GeneNA NA NA NA NA NA"
```

Some genes start or end with 'NA', so to avoid getting rid of those NAs, the gsub regex has to specify the position of the NA in the string... Something like:
`test2 <- gsub('^ NA$', "", test$Column1)`, with `^` indicating that ' NA' has to be at the start and `$` at the end of the string... I am sure it's something simple, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong? (As I am not very familiar with these regex symbols)

[UPDATE] - Desired output

```
head(test2)
Column1 
[1] "Gene1 Gene2 Gene3" 
[2] "Gene41 NAGene218 GeneX"
[3] "Gene19 GeneNA"
```

Comment: What is the desired output?  Please display it for the example.

Comment: Hi there - I've updated the post to be more clear about the desired output. 

@Clemsang, your suggestion does not work unfortunately, because some gene names start with NA - the output is cut on the first time a gene that starts with 'NA' appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
test$Column1 <- gsub("^NA(?:\\s+NA)*\\b\\s*|\\s*\\bNA(?:\\s+NA)*$", "", test$Column1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/26Cmdm/1/)

**Details**

- `^NA(?:\s+NA)*\b\s*` - Alternative 1:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `NA` - `NA` string
  - `(?:\s+NA)*` - 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and `NA` text
  - `\b` - make sure there is a word boundary (no `NAGene` match should occur)
  - `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s*\bNA(?:\s+NA)*$` - Alternative 2:

  - `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\b` - make sure there is a word boundary (no `GeneNA` match should occur)
  - `NA` - `NA` string
  - `(?:\s+NA)*` - 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and `NA` text
  - `$`  - end of string.

Comment: FYI: In case you find issues with performance or any weird behavior, add `perl=TRUE` argument to `gsub`, `gsub("^NA(?:\\s+NA)*\\b\\s*|\\s*\\bNA(?:\\s+NA)*$", "", test$Column1, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!! (it worked fine without the perl option, actually)

(I really thought this was going to be a relatively easy issue, but the complexity of this regex is out of this world - at least at a first glance haha)

Answer (score 1):

Try this from `stringr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(column1 = c("Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 NA NA NA NA" ,
                           "Gene41 NAGene218 GeneX NA",
                           "Gene19 GeneNA NA NA NA NA NA"))

test %>%
 mutate(column1 = str_remove_all(column1, " NA|NA"))
```

Comment: Can you try it on `"Gene41 NAGene218 GeneX NA"`

Comment: Try that, didn't see that other NA there.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about the desired output (I updated the post now to include this). Thanks for this suggestion, but this command does not work for my case, because it removes genes that start with NA too (NAGene218, in my example).

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 NA NA NA NA", "Gene41 NAGene218 GeneX NA", "Gene19 GeneNA NA NA NA NA NA")

str_split(x, "\\s", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_all(~str_remove(.x, "^(NA)|(NA)$"))

# V1     V2      V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   
# <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#   1 Gene1  Gene2   Gene3 ""    ""    ""    ""   
# 2 Gene41 Gene218 GeneX ""    ""    ""    ""   
# 3 Gene19 Gene    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is also not working, as it's removing NAs from gene names too (GeneNA became Gene, and NAGene218 became Gene218). I apologize that I wasn't clearer on the desired output, but I have updated the original question now.